# AKNodeOutputPlot not functioning correctly with Inter App Audio

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I recently added Audiobus and IAA support for my app. Unfortunately, although the audio functions correctly, the AKNodeOutputPlot just shows a flat line and no waveforms. I tried creating a mixer earlier in my signal chain and adding that noded to the plot, but the plot still shows a flat line. I tried changing the plot type to AKNodeFFTPlot. This works and I can see the visualization, but it is not the type of plot I want to use. The current code for my plot view is as follows.

```
private lazy var oscilliscopeView: AKNodeOutputPlot = {
    let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot(Conductor.shared.voltageControlledAmplifier, frame: .zero)
    plot.plotType = .buffer
    plot.shouldFill = true
    plot.shouldMirror = true
    plot.color = .white
    plot.backgroundColor = .clear
    plot.clipsToBounds = true
    plot.isHidden = true
    plot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return plot
}()
```

Conductor.shared.voltageControlledAmplifier is not the node set to the AudioKit.output. Another node further up the chain is used for that. Any thoughts on what might be causing the AKNodeOutputPlot to malfunction?

Comment: Just to be on the same page, which version of AudioKit are you using?

Comment: Hmm, I got independent corraboration that this is happening on the latest branch.  Investigating...

Comment: From looking at the code, AKNodeOutputPlot is trying to do the right thing, while the FFT plot does nothing at all.  I think I'll just remove the "do the right thing" stuff from the node output plot.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yeah, I am using the latest version of AudioKit.

Comment: What do you mean by the "do the right thing" stuff? Does removing this mean AKNodeOutputPlot won't work at all with Audiobus or that it will?

Comment: AudioKit responds to IAA connections and disconnections in AKNodeOutputPlot.  The FFT plot doesn't.

Comment: I just tested the plot on our synth, and it works for me, but not for my collaborator, so something weird is going on.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I hope you can find out whats going wrong.

Comment: I just got the FFT plot to work in both Audiobus and IAA, the code is on the develop branch.  Thing is I made the code mirror AKNodeOutputPlot, which is working for me, but not for you.  Still waiting on collaborating with someone who is seeing the same issue.

Comment: Cool! If it helps at all, I am testing IAA through Garageband. It might just be a problem with Garageband. Also, I was working on a bug with iOS 9 before and I added you as a collaborator to the project. If you want to look at the code, I have committed all my latest changes to Github.

Comment: Yeah, I use GarageBand too.  Thanks for reminding me that you already invited me to the project, I always forget whose project is whose.

Comment: Grant, I can't get it working on actual iPad because I'm not on your dev team. I don't actually have an email address for you or else I'd contact you off of this list.  I'd love to invite you to AudioKit's slack group.

Comment: Okay, so the person who was saying that they can't get the plot to work in IAA/Audiobus, corroborating your findings, now says that it works, so yeah, if we can investigate this off SO that would be good.